# Python functions simple and dumb

Tags: python

I have been studying coding on my own and some how I have been stuck, not being able to compile the same solution:

my code:

```
def append_size(lst):
    num = len(lst)
    lst = lst.append(num)
    return lst
print(append_size([23, 42, 108]))
```

solution:

```
def append_size(lst):
    lst.append(len(lst))
    return lst
print(append_size([23, 42, 108]))
```

first one gives out "None" and second one gives out the list.
tell me why.

Thank you

Comment: Because you return the result of `lst.append(num)`. and `lst.append(num)` returns `None`.

Comment: This is common in python. Methods that modify an object don't also return that object. Doing so would add a reference count update and since there is rarely any reason why someone would want the object, its just a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Its because in the first one, you assign `lst` the result of the call `lst.append()`

The `.append()` method returns `None` so assigning it to a variable and returning it... Would return `None`

While in the second case. No such assignment takes place

```
# first code
lst = lst.append(x)  # end up assigning None to lst

#second code
lst.append(x)  # no unwanted assignments
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and time Muhd. :)

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` wont return anything (just `None`), it just modifies a list. So when you do `lst = lst.append(list)` you are basically assigning `None` to `lst`.
Try this instead

```
def append_size(lst):
    num = len(lst)
    lst.append(num)
    return lst
print(append_size([23, 42, 108]))
```

Comment: @MuhdMairaj technically, Python functions *always return something*. Unlike some langauges, there are no "void" functions or "routines". By *default* if you don't explicitly return something, a Python will automatically return `None`

Comment: Thank you for explanation and time my friend. :)